# Optimize query to fetch tuples from index directly

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

I want to optimize a large SQL query that has around 500 SQL lines and is a little slow, it takes 1 to 5 seconds to execute in an interactive system.

I saw this munin graph

[image: graph2]

That is not the same as this graph

[image: graph1]

What I understand from the first graph (showing scans) is that the indexes are being used in `where` or `order by` sentences, only to search a tuple that matches some rules (boolean expression).

The second graph I'm not really sure what it means by "tuple access"

Question1: What is the meaning of "tuple access"?

So I'm thinking that I can make an optimization step forward if I could rewrite some parts of this big query to fetch more tuples using the indexes and less sequentially, using the information in the second graph.

Question2: Am I correct? Would it be better that the second graph show more index fetched and less sequentially read?

Question3: In case this is correct, could you provide a SQL example in which the tuples are index-fetched opposed to one in which they are sequentially read?

Note: In the questions, I'm only referring to the second graph

Comment: If you want to talk about optimization you should show the actual query, show the data structures, show the indices and show the exact version of SQL. 500 lines is quite a lot.

Comment: Exact version of PostgreSQL that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, trying to optimize graphs like this is a mistake unless you have a specific performance problem.  It is not in fact always better to retrieve tuples from the indexes.  These things are very complex decisions which depend on specifics of table, table access, the sort of material you are retrieving and more.

The fact is that a query plan that works for one quantity of data may not work as well for another.

Particularly if you have a lot of small tables, sequential scans will, for example, always beat index scans.

So what you want to do is to start by finding the slow queries, running them under `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and looking for opportunities to add appropriate indexes.  You can't do this without looking at the query plan and the actual query, which is why you always want to look at that.

In other words, your graph just gives you a sense of access patterns.  It does not give you enough information to do any sort of real performance optimizations.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me! Also, there are three tables in the query, a big one that is self cross joined, and two smaller.